# Disable the status bar in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to disable the default status bar on tmux. I prefer to treat screen/tmux as persistant session managers, and deprecate the menu/window stuff in favor of my system window manager. I suspect Tmux could be better for this role than screen.

And if that's possible, can I do it at runtime with a chord?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
set -g status off
```

You can enter it with *Prefix* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> by default) `:set ...`, or from shell with `tmux set ...`, or bind a key with `bind-key x set ...`.

Comment: I would only add to you answer the detail that to enter a command you don't have to press "Ctrl + Prefix", but only "Prefix".
Prefix **is** the _whole key combination_ that has to be followed by ":".

By the way, to some "prefix" doesn't even include the CTRL key at all (for instance, my prefix is Alt-e).

Comment: +1. @grawity is there a way to enable the status bar automatically when there are multiple tabs?

Comment: Is it possible to set this in the ~/.tmux.conf file? If yes, how?

Comment: Found the problem. I was using powerline and loading the powerline specific settings for tmux after setting the status to off. This overrode the settings (stupid mistake on my part)

Comment: @Yang This is possible using tmux hooks (if you have a recent enough tmux version). Check the man page.

Comment: That's confusing wording.  To try to clarify: with the Ctrl+b prefix, this is what to type:  `Ctrl+b: set -g status off`  including the colon (:).